# On installing driver for HP Laserjet Pro M15a

Tags: gtk, printer, hp

Does anyone know how to install driver for HP Laserjet Pro M15a for Ubuntu 19.04? I tried

```
./hplip-3.19.6.run 
Creating directory hplip-3.19.6
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.19.6 Self Extracting Archive./hplip-3.19.6.run: 369: cd: can't cd to hplip-3.19.6
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................/hplip-3.19.6.run: 371: cd: can't cd to hplip-3.19.6
chown: cannot read directory './hplip-3.19.6': Permission denied
chgrp: cannot read directory './hplip-3.19.6': Permission denied

./hplip-3.19.6.run: 382: cd: can't cd to hplip-3.19.6

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.6)
HPLIP Installer ver. 5.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Installer log saved in: hplip-install_Tue-09-Jul-2019_14:52:59.log

\
note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.
-Gtk-Message: 14:53:00.708: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
error: debian-buster/sid version is not supported, so all dependencies may not be installed. However trying to install using debian-9.8 version packages.

Press 'y' to continue auto installation. Press 'n' to quit auto instalation(y=yes, n=no*):
```

But why do it complains about the canberra-gtk-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the packaged version instead:

```
sudo apt install hplip
```

The version available in Ubuntu 19.04 includes full support for the M15a.

The `canberra-gtk-module` is a warning related to Gtk event sounds; it’s innocuous and can be ignored.